How to import modules from other local directories in python?
I've been using JavaScript and can say I'm used to how the imports of modules are done but when it's Python, I get confused as to how to import modules from local directories. Be it two or more levels up.
In JavaScript it was pretty easy as you could just use require function to import something. It would be of great help if someone could help me with the python module imports. An example would help a lot.
Here is my code directory structure...
- data_structures_and_algorithms_python
-- algorithms
-- data_structures
--- LinkedList
---- SinglyLinkedList
----- SinglyLinkedList_1.py
----- SinglyLinkedList_2.py
--- Node
---- Node_1.py
---- Node_2.py

I'm in SinglyLinkedList_2.py and want to import a Node class from Node_2.py which is in the Node directory. How do I do that?
The first thing I did was I tried importing sys and os and then navigating to the directory where the class is located and then sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) and then  from {FILENAME} import {CLASSNAME}. This felt a little bit too much to do.
The second was just by using sys.path.append('location/of/module') and then importing the same way I did in the first attempt.

import first_level.second_level.module_name . . . for however many subfolders are needed. In fact, Python is a little bit easier than JavaScript.

What is "local directories" in this context? Local to your current working directory? The .py module? Other modules in a python package? Its common to install modules and packages so that you don't have to worry about where they are on disk. Is that workable in your situation?

Added the code directory structure just now.. Take a look and let me know. @JohnGordon

@tdelaney Yes local to my current working directory.. I added the code directory structure for you to look through.. let me know how to import it

@D.L so according to my directory structure which is in the post... Do I first start from the root directory i.e data_structures_and_algorithms_python and go down from there or is it from linear_data_structures directory. let me know. thankyou!

Next, show us the exact command you are using to run the code.

py SinglyLinkedList_2.py @JohnGordon

you can naturally import from subdirectories and not neighbouring directories. The reason for this is that it could quite easily lead to circular references...

Hmm.. I think I found a way to import properly... So you import like this right from ...Node.Node_2 import Node. And to make this work you need to run this command in the top level directory data_structures py -m linear_data_structures.LinkedList.SinglyLinkedList.SinglyLinkedList_2. Is this the typical way people do it? @D.L

Basically yes. Python doesn't import files, it imports modules by name. It finds modules by name based on some factors; it'll look in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, which also includes the current working directory by default. So it depends how you run it and from where and how your environment is set up. That may seem complicated, but allows more flexibility in where you actually install modules all over your system. In JS with modern preprocessors/compilers the situation is very similar, where you can also define library roots and aliases that will be resolved.
